# magento add to cart with change price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, addtocart

After changing price **Rs.31078** how to add it to the cart.

How to get the price dynamically?

```
$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            $product_id=$item->getProductId();
            $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            // echo"<pre>";
            // print_r($_product);
            // exit();
            $newprice=$_product->getPrice();-->i need 31078  product change price.

            // ****** But in cart i am getting 15128. ? ******

            // Set the custom price
            $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
            $item->setFinalPrice($newprice);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

this is the change price ,i need to add to cart .
But in my cart its taking  admin panel product price
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create observer with "checkout_cart_product_add_after" event.

after that in your observer file use below function.

```
public function customPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        $specialPrice = 5;
        $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

}
```

Comment: its not a special price. how to set the price?

Comment: $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
            $product_id=$item->getProductId();
            $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
            $newprice=$_product->getPrice();------------->i need  Rs 31078,but in cart i am getting check screen shot
            $item->setCustomPrice($newprice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newprice);
            $item->setFinalPrice($newprice);
            // Enable super mode on the product.
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

Comment: how to set price dynamically $newprice=$_product->getPrice();--